# Non-injective polynomial map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, injective on lines

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, transcendence-degree

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$,
$(x,y) \mapsto (f(x,y),g(x,y))$, where $f(x,y),g(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$,
each is of $(1,1)$-degree at least one, and $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{R}$ (their Jacobian $\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]-\{0\}$).

Assume that for every $a,b,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,
if $F(a,\lambda)=F(b,\lambda)$ then $a=b$,
namely, $F$ is injective on horizontal lines $y=\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

> (1) It would be nice to have an example of such $F$ which is non-injective.
>   (I guess there exists such $F$ which is non-injective?).

A second question:
Assume that for every $a,b,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,
if $F(a,\lambda a)=F(b,\lambda b)$ then $a=b$,
namely, $F$ is injective on lines through the origin.

> (2) It would be nice to have an example of such $F$ which is non-injective.
>   (I guess there exists such $F$ which is non-injective?).

A third question: $F$ which satisfies both the first and second conditions,
still does not have to be injective?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? If not, the question is trivial.

Comment: Take $F(x,y)=(x+y,1)$ (for the first question).

Comment: @ElliotG, thank you. $F$ is a polynomial map, so it is continuous.

Comment: @lulu, thank you. I forgot to require that each of $f$ and $g$ is of $(1,1)$-degree at least one; does it matter?

Comment: Doesn't matter.  Take $F(x,y)=(x+y,x+y)$ if you prefer.  And for the second question take $F(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$.

Comment: @lulu $(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,x-y)$ is injective, right?

Comment: @stewbasic  Yes, you are correct.  My error.  My example fails for the second question.

Comment: I think that I also wish to require that $f$ and $g$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{R}$ (so $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y,x+y)$ will not work). I will add this to the question.

Comment: Still for the first question we can take $F(x,y)=(x,y^2)$.

Comment: @stewbasic, thank you! (1) Are there additional ('non-trivial') conditions that will guarantee injectivity? (2) What about my third question? (probably there exists such $F$ which is non-injective).

Comment: btw in the second case, do you want $F$ to be injective on the set $\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$? Your statement in terms of $\lambda$ doesn't imply this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\{(0,y)\mid y\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Nice question. I guess that I want to add this vertical line.

Comment: I had in mind $f$ and $g$ each is a sum of monomials of odd $(1,1)$-degrees and satisfying at least one of the two conditions, or perhaps both.

Comment: @stewbasic, $F: (x,y) \mapsto (x,y^2)$ does not work for the second question, since it is not injective on the vertical line $\{(0,y)\}$: $F(0,1)=(0,1)=F(0,-1)$. Is there a way to fix that? (I guess this is the reason why you asked me specifically about that line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be given by
$$F(x,y)=(x^3+y^3,2x+y)$$

Then $F$ is injective on every horizontal line, and on every line through the origin, but $F$ is not injective, since for example, the equation
$$F(x,y)=\bigl({\small{\frac{1}{4}}},1\bigr)$$
has more than one solution.

Comment: Nice example, thanks! I guess that any $f(x,y)=u(x)+v(y)$ and $g(x,y)=\tilde{u}(x)+\tilde{v}(y)$, with appropriate $u(x),\tilde{u}(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $v(y),\tilde{v}(y) \in \mathbb{R}[y]$ will yield an example. Are there additional, general enough, additional conditions that will guarantee injectivity of such $F$?

Comment: @user237522: Care needs to be taken in the choices. For example:$\;(1)\;$If $F(x,y)=(x+y,2x+y)$, then $F$ would be injective;$\;(2)\;$If $F(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,2x+y)$, then $F$ would not be injective on the line $y=-2x$;$\;(3)\;$If $F(x,y)=(x^3+y^3,x+y)$, then $F$ would not be injective on the line $y=-x$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In your example, $F$ is also injective on all vertical lines $\{(\lambda,y)\}$, isn't it? This is very nice.

Comment: What about injectivity on lines $y=\lambda x+ \mu$? (I am trying to check this now).

Comment: If $F$ is not injective, then of course, $F$ is not injective on _some_ line.

Comment: Oh, you are right... then necessarily there exists $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $F$ is not injective on $y= \lambda x + \mu$.